# How can I solve graceful-fs version warning of gulp

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, gruntjs, gulp

When i install gulp for ionic.it shows some warning but there is no warning or error when i install grunt..So how can I use grunt instead of gulp for ionic app development??

when i try to install gulp it shows these lines.

F:\android\ionic\ionwork\mynote>npm install -g gulp

npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade
 to lodash@^4.0.0.

npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail o
n node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.

C:\Users\Thinkpad\AppData\Roaming\npm\gulp -> C:\Users\Thinkpad\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js

I have tried to upgrade and gone through many solution and resources but could not find good solution... :(

Comment: What do you mean by "install gulp for ionic"? What command do you use and what error do you see? you should really try to resolve your problem with gulp instead of trying to switch to grunt. Using grunt when everybody else is using gulp..

Comment: If you need help, please specify as much details as possible......

Comment: @iCediCe  and  Horrible Guy I have added the details...... please help me if you can....

Comment: Don't think you have an actual issue here. What happens if you type 'gulp -v' ?

Comment: @iCediCe when i type gulp -v then it shows the version ,does that mean that the installation was successful? if so then why it shows those warnings?? if you have any idea please share...

Comment: I think you should just ignore those errors... but again, why do you want grunt? you really should go with gulp.